# Associating FXML and Controller in Guice's Module configuration

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javafx-2, guice, fxml

In my Guice Module I want to associate FXML files and their controllers, currently it looks like this:

```
public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule 
{   
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        // associate controllers and fxml files
        bind(MainController.class).toInstance((MainController)loadController("/main.fxml"));
        bind(SubController.class).toInstance((SubController)loadController("/content.fxml"));
    }

    protected Object loadController(String url)
    {
        InputStream fxmlStream = null;
        try
        {
            fxmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(url));


            loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {

                public Object call(Class<?> clazz) { // clazz because class is a reserved word
                    return injector.getInstance(clazz); // PROBLEM: no access to the injector here
                }
            });

            loader.load(fxmlStream);
            return loader.getController();
        }

        // [..] exception handling

    }
}**strong text**
```

However in the `loadController(String url)` method I get problems with that line:

```
return injector.getInstance(clazz); // PROBLEM: no access to the injector here
```

How can I access Guice's `getInstance` method from within a Guice Module? Is that or something equivalent possible?

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of **fx-guice**, an open-source library that can be used to use Guice in your JavaFX applications. The library is licensed using the Apache License  v2 and can be obtained via the central [Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.cathive.fx%22%20AND%20a%3A%22fx-guice%22).

Even though it might *not* answer your exact question, I suggest you have a look at my project, which comes bundled with quite a few examples:
Project home: → http://github.com/cathive/fx-guice/

The main idea of my framework is:
Instead of extending "javafx.application.Application" you extend "com.cathive.fx.GuiceApplication". You can then simply @Inject instaces of "GuiceFXMLLoader" wherever you want and can use these special FXMLLoader instances to load your UI definitions. Within your FXML-controller classes you can mix @Inject and @FXML annoations as you like.
→ http://bit.ly/139fKQV

My framework also offers a bunch of functionality concerning "Guicified" JavaFX components, which bind together a Java class and a single FXML file (using a special annotation: "@FXMLComponent"). I wrote a short "Calculator" example whose sources can be obtained from the Github pages (see above). The relevant portions of the code can be found here:
CalculatorAppPane.java: → http://bit.ly/10YMVoM
CalculatorAppPane.fxml: → http://bit.ly/13loYv8

Hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest one of many approaches to associate a Controller to an **FXML** file, I will suppose that you are using the ***fx:controller*** tag in your **FXML** file.

for the demonstration purpose, I will implement a demo app hosted on [github](https://github.com/tarrsalah/stackoverflow.guice.fx) with one button in the middle of the stage.

[image]

```
Demo__
     |___ App.java
     |___ AppModule.java
     |___ IController.java
     |___ Controller.java
     |___ InjectingFXMLLoader.java
     |___ fxml
              |__view.fxml
```

### View.fxml

note that we refer to the interface in the ***fx:controller*** in the **FXML** file, and not to the implementation, so we can reuse the fxml view with other controllers implementing the interface.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="org.tarrsalah.stackoverflow.guice.fx.IController" >
    <center>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="fx_print" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#printButton" text="Print !" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </children>
            <BorderPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="20.0" top="10.0" />
            </BorderPane.margin>
        </HBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

### IController

an interface that the controller must implement , the `printButton()` to print a message to the screen , and `getRoot()` to get the Panel View.

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public interface IController extends Initializable {

    public void printButton();  

    public Parent getRoot();
}
```

### Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public class Controller implements IController {

    @FXML
    Parent root;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }

    public Parent getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void printButton() {
        System.out.println("Hello Guice !!");
    }
}
```

### InjectingFXMLLoader

a class with one static method that get a concrete implementation of a **controller** and 
**URL** of the **FXML** file and return the controller of the view.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class InjectingFXMLLoader {
    /**
     * 
     * @param <N>
     * @param injector
     * @return a controller injected within an FXML.
     */
    public static <N> N loadFXMLController(final N controller, URL url) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(url);
        loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {

            public Object call(Class<?> p) {
                return controller;
            }
        });
        loader.load();
        return loader.getController();
    }
}
```

### AppModule

in the  guice module , we use the InjectingFXMLLoader class to associate a concrete implementation of the controller with the corresponding **FXML** file. using a [@Provides](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) method.

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return IController
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Provides
    public IController getIController() throws IOException {
        return InjectingFXMLLoader.loadFXMLController(new Controller(), getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/view.fxml"));
    }
}
```

### App

the main class that show the view

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(SceneBuilder
                .create()
                .root(Guice.createInjector(new AppModule()).getInstance(IController.class).getRoot())
                .height(160)
                .width(200)
                .build());
        stage.show();
    }
}
```